# How do I get the coordinates of a mouse click on a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, canvas

What's the simplest way to add a click event handler to a canvas element that will return the x and y coordinates of the click (relative to the canvas element)?

No legacy browser compatibility required, Safari, Opera and Firefox will do.

Comment: This should not be any different from getting mouse events from normal dom elements. [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html) has a good reference on that.

Comment: The code you list above only works when the canvas isn't deep inside other containers.  In general you need to use something like the jquery offset function 
        [var testDiv = $('#testDiv');
 var offset = testDiv.offset();]
to get the correct offset in a cross browser way.  This is a real pain in the ***.

Comment: The code posted above with Update fails to work if the page containing the canvas scrolls.

Comment: I removed my old "answer" that was included as an update to the question. As mentioned, it was out of date and incomplete.

Comment: event.layerX and event.layerY are now in Chrome, FF, and MSIE(9)

Comment: Since there is like 50 answers here, I recommend scrolling to this guys answer: patriques - a good and simple 5 liner.

Comment: This question has become horribly cluttered. More up-to-date links here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607924/click-in-canvas-is-three-pixels-off

Answer (score 279, accepted):

If you like simplicity but still want cross-browser functionality I found this solution worked best for me. This is a simplification of @Aldekein´s solution but **without jQuery**.

```
function getCursorPosition(canvas, event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
    const x = event.clientX - rect.left
    const y = event.clientY - rect.top
    console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y)
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    getCursorPosition(canvas, e)
})
```

Comment: If the page is scrolled down, I guess one should also take the document's scroll offset into consideration.

Comment: @PeppeL-G bounding client rectangle calculates that for you. You can easily test it in console before you post a comment (that's what I did).

Comment: @TomášZato, oh, `getBoundingClientRect` returns positions relative to the view port? Then my guess was wrong. I never tested it out since this was never a problem for me, and I kindly wanted to warn other readers of a potentially problem I saw, but thank you for your clarification.

Comment: What did I do wrong? I use `canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', getCursorPosition(canvas, this), false);` to trigger this function and I get `x: NaN y: N` in the console besides it seems like it only fires once.

Comment: And if I use `document.getElementById('blah').onclick = function getCursorPosition(canvas, event)`, I will get `canvas.getBoundingClientRect is not a function at HTMLCanvasElement.getCursorPosition`...

Comment: Okay I guess I figured it out, if I use `document.getElementById('blah').onclick =` I will simply remove the `canvas` and write `function getCursorPosition(event)`

Comment: This doesn't work if the canvas is scaled. Not sure if that's a browser bug.

Comment: It should be mentioned that using `getBoundingClientRect` causes reflow, often a serious performance bottleneck. Using `offsetX` and `offsetY` in modern browsers is the only correct way to do it.

Comment: Add usage for someone like me: `var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasID'); canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) { getCursorPosition(canvas, e);});`

Comment: Unhelpful without usage: how to add the event listener; how to get the canvas element.

Comment: @SnowOnion Added your usage example to the answer. THANKS

Comment: @patriques My pleasure :)

Comment: May need to scale it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17130415/8804293

Comment: This worked great for me, and even properly handled margins/padding (which other techniques choked on).  Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This doesn't work with scroll!!!!!

Answer (score 181):

**Update** (5/5/16): [patriques' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18053642/1026023) should be used instead, as it's both simpler and more reliable.

---

Since the canvas isn't always styled relative to the entire page, the `canvas.offsetLeft/Top` doesn't always return what you need. It will return the number of pixels it is offset relative to its offsetParent element, which can be something like a `div` element containing the canvas with a `position: relative` style applied. To account for this you need to loop through the chain of `offsetParent`s, beginning with the canvas element itself. This code works perfectly for me, tested in Firefox and Safari but should work for all.

```
function relMouseCoords(event){
    var totalOffsetX = 0;
    var totalOffsetY = 0;
    var canvasX = 0;
    var canvasY = 0;
    var currentElement = this;

    do{
        totalOffsetX += currentElement.offsetLeft - currentElement.scrollLeft;
        totalOffsetY += currentElement.offsetTop - currentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    while(currentElement = currentElement.offsetParent)

    canvasX = event.pageX - totalOffsetX;
    canvasY = event.pageY - totalOffsetY;

    return {x:canvasX, y:canvasY}
}
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.relMouseCoords = relMouseCoords;
```

The last line makes things convenient for getting the mouse coordinates relative to a canvas element. All that's needed to get the useful coordinates is

```
coords = canvas.relMouseCoords(event);
canvasX = coords.x;
canvasY = coords.y;
```

Comment: is this using the library prototype? Is there a way to do it without a library?

Comment: No, it is using the builtin javascript prototype object --- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Prototype-based_programming

Comment: my Chrome has `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY` attributes, so I modified your solution by adding `if (event.offsetX !== undefined && event.offsetY !== undefined) { return {x:event.offsetX, y:event.offsetY}; }`. looks like it works.

Comment: Baczek is correct about Chrome's `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY` which also works in IE9. For Firefox (tested w/ v13) you can use `event.layerX` and `event.layerY`.

Comment: For this to work when the canvas is positioned on a scrollable container I had to add:

totalOffsetX += currentElement.offsetLeft - currentElement.scrollLeft;
totalOffsetY += currentElement.offsetTop - currentElement.scrollTop;

Comment: @amirpc You're right. Updated my answer to accomodate scrolling containers.

Comment: I additionally added this:

`canvasX = event.pageX - totalOffsetX - document.body.scrollLeft;
canvasY = event.pageY - totalOffsetY - document.body.scrollTop;`

Comment: @amirpc Is that necessary? Doesn't `pageX/Y` ignore the scrolling on the page?

Comment: It was necessary for my situation but I had nested scrollable elements. I haven't thought about it particularly hard though, just accepted my change once it worked :)

Comment: To make it work stand-alone for any event rather than as a prototype  method on Canvas, I changed `var currentElement = this;` to `var currentElement = event.currentElement;`

Comment: I tested that the 'event.layerX' works for Chrome (version-27.0.1453.110 m) as well; not only FF.

Comment: This final version on answer didn't work for me. On Firefox, if whole screen is scrolled, I got the displaced value as output. What worked for me was a very similar solution, given on http://stackoverflow.com/a/10816667/578749 that instead of event.pageX/Y, it subtracted calculated offset from event.clientX/Y. Could someone review this and explain?

Comment: The method isn't very fast... Couldn't you cache something after first run?

Comment: This worked for a simple page, but once I buried it in a complex page, it no longer worked. However, patriques' answer did work on the complex page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18053642/1026023

Comment: I get an error `ReferenceError: canvas is not defined`

Comment: I am geting an error ReferenceError: event not defined.

Answer (score 82):

**Edit 2018:** This answer is pretty old and it uses checks for old browsers that are not necessary anymore, as the `clientX` and `clientY` properties work in all current browsers. You might want to check out [Patriques Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18053642/540725) for a simpler, more recent solution.

**Original Answer:**
As described in an article i found back then but exists no longer:

```
var x;
var y;
if (e.pageX || e.pageY) { 
  x = e.pageX;
  y = e.pageY;
}
else { 
  x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft; 
  y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
} 
x -= gCanvasElement.offsetLeft;
y -= gCanvasElement.offsetTop;
```

Worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: This solution doesn't always work - Ryan Artecona's answer works in the more general case when the canvas is not necessarily positioned relative to the whole page.

Comment: This solution is not fitted if performance matters, since Dom access are done on each click / move. And getBoundingClientRect exists now, and is more elegant.

Answer (score 40):

Modern browser's now handle this for you. Chrome, IE9, and Firefox support the offsetX/Y like this, passing in the event from the click handler.

```
function getRelativeCoords(event) {
    return { x: event.offsetX, y: event.offsetY };
}
```

Most modern browsers also support layerX/Y, however Chrome and IE use layerX/Y for  the absolute offset of the click on the page including margin, padding, etc. In Firefox, layerX/Y and offsetX/Y are equivalent, but offset didn't previously exist. So, for compatibility with slightly older browsers, you can use:

```
function getRelativeCoords(event) {
    return { x: event.offsetX || event.layerX, y: event.offsetY || event.layerY };
}
```

Comment: interesting how layerX, layerY is defined on both Chrome and Firefox, but on Chrome it is inaccurate (or means something else).

Comment: @JulianMann Thanks for the info. I've updated this answer based on more current support. Looks like you can get away with offsetX/Y almost universally now.

Answer (score 22):

So this is both simple but a slightly more complicated topic than it seems.

First off there are usually to conflated questions here

1. **How to get element relative mouse coordinates**
2. **How to get canvas pixel mouse coordinates for the 2D Canvas API or WebGL**

so, answers

## How to get element relative mouse coordinates

Whether or not the element is a canvas getting element relative mouse coordinates is the same for all elements.

There are 2 simple answers to the question "How to get canvas relative mouse coordinates"

#### Simple answer #1 use `offsetX` and `offsetY`

```
canvas.addEventListner('mousemove', (e) => {
  const x = e.offsetX;
  const y = e.offsetY;
});
```

This answer works in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. Unlike all the other event values `offsetX` and `offsetY` take CSS transforms into account.

The biggest problem with `offsetX` and `offsetY` is as of 2019/05 they don't exist on touch events and so can't be used with iOS Safari. They do exist on Pointer Events which exist in Chrome and Firefox but not Safari although [apparently Safari is working on it](https://webkit.org/blog/8419/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-67/).

Another issue is the events must be on the canvas itself. If you put them on some other element or the window you can not later choose the canvas to be your point of reference.

### Simple answer #2 use `clientX`, `clientY` and `canvas.getBoundingClientRect`

If you don't care about CSS transforms the next simplest answer is to call `canvas. getBoundingClientRect()` and subtract the left from `clientX` and `top` from `clientY` as in

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  const y = e.clientY - rect.top;
});
```

This will work as long as there are no CSS transforms. It also works with touch events and so will work with Safari iOS

```
canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
  const rect = canvas. getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = e.touches[0].clientX - rect.left;
  const y = e.touches[0].clientY - rect.top;
});
```

## How to get canvas pixel mouse coordinates for the 2D Canvas API

For this we need to take the values we got above and convert from the size the canvas is displayed to the number of pixels in the canvas itself

with `canvas.getBoundingClientRect` and `clientX` and `clientY`

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const elementRelativeX = e.clientX - rect.left;
  const elementRelativeY = e.clientY - rect.top;
  const canvasRelativeX = elementRelativeX * canvas.width / rect.width;
  const canvasRelativeY = elementRelativeY * canvas.height / rect.height;
});
```

or with `offsetX` and `offsetY`

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  const elementRelativeX = e.offsetX;
  const elementRelativeY = e.offsetY;
  const canvasRelativeX = elementRelativeX * canvas.width / canvas.clientWidth;
  const canvasRelativeY = elementRelativeY * canvas.height / canvas.clientHeight;
});
```

## Note: **In all cases do not add padding or borders to the canvas. Doing so will massively complicate the code. Instead of you want a border or padding surround the canvas in some other element and add the padding and or border to the outer element.**

Working example using `event.offsetX`, `event.offsetY`

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('canvas')].forEach((canvas) => {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.canvas.width  = ctx.canvas.clientWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = ctx.canvas.clientHeight;
  let count = 0;

  function draw(e, radius = 1) {
    const pos = {
      x: e.offsetX * canvas.width  / canvas.clientWidth,
      y: e.offsetY * canvas.height / canvas.clientHeight,
    };
    document.querySelector('#debug').textContent = count;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = hsl((count++ % 100) / 100, 1, 0.5);
    ctx.fill();
  }

  function preventDefault(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  if (window.PointerEvent) {
    canvas.addEventListener('pointermove', (e) => {
      draw(e, Math.max(Math.max(e.width, e.height) / 2, 1));
    });
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', preventDefault, {passive: false});
    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault, {passive: false});
  } else {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', preventDefault);
  }
});

function hsl(h, s, l) {
  return `hsl(${h * 360 | 0},${s * 100 | 0}%,${l * 100 | 0}%)`;
}
```

```css
.scene {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation-duration: 16s;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(  0deg) rotateY(  0deg); }
  to   { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(720deg); }
}

.cube__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.cube__face--front  { background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2); transform: rotateY(  0deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--right  { background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2); transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--back   { background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2); transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--left   { background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2); transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--top    { background: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2); transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--bottom { background: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.2); transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px); }
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="cube">
    <canvas class="cube__face cube__face--front"></canvas>
    <canvas class="cube__face cube__face--back"></canvas>
    <canvas class="cube__face cube__face--right"></canvas>
    <canvas class="cube__face cube__face--left"></canvas>
    <canvas class="cube__face cube__face--top"></canvas>
    <canvas class="cube__face cube__face--bottom"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
<pre id="debug"></pre>
```

Working example using `canvas.getBoundingClientRect` and `event.clientX` and `event.clientY`

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width  = ctx.canvas.clientWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = ctx.canvas.clientHeight;
let count = 0;

function draw(e, radius = 1) {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const pos = {
    x: (e.clientX - rect.left) * canvas.width  / canvas.clientWidth,
    y: (e.clientY - rect.top) * canvas.height / canvas.clientHeight,
  };
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = hsl((count++ % 100) / 100, 1, 0.5);
  ctx.fill();
}

function preventDefault(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

if (window.PointerEvent) {
  canvas.addEventListener('pointermove', (e) => {
    draw(e, Math.max(Math.max(e.width, e.height) / 2, 1));
  });
  canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', preventDefault, {passive: false});
  canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault, {passive: false});
} else {
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', preventDefault);
}

function hsl(h, s, l) {
  return `hsl(${h * 360 | 0},${s * 100 | 0}%,${l * 100 | 0}%)`;
}
```

```css
canvas { background: #FED; }
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="100" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></canvas>
<div>canvas deliberately has differnt CSS size vs drawingbuffer size</div>
```

Comment: This worked well for me. One comment, the offsetX/Y version of the code has two typos when handling Y values. The fixed lines are:
  const elementRelativeY = e.offsetY;
  const canvasRelativeY = elementRelativeY * canvas.height / canvas.clientHeight;

Comment: thanks. fixed... note: you could have edited the answer. Your edit will be reviewed

Comment: also see Mozilla's [mousedown event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event) example

Comment: the first one on the 2D canvas API worked for me nicely :)

Comment: I just wanted to add  a comment saying out of all the answers - this is the only correct one. It accounts for a canvas being positioned anywhere at any zoom, and having the canvas internal scale of any values.

Answer (score 18):

According to fresh [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#mousepos) the `clientX` and `clientY` methods are supported in all major browsers.
So, here it goes - the good, working code that works in a scrolling div on a page with scrollbars:

```
function getCursorPosition(canvas, event) {
var x, y;

canoffset = $(canvas).offset();
x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft - Math.floor(canoffset.left);
y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop - Math.floor(canoffset.top) + 1;

return [x,y];
}
```

This also requires [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) for `$(canvas).offset()`.

Comment: Equivalent to @N4ppeL answer.

Answer (score 13):

I made a full demostration that works in every browser with the full source code of the solution of this problem: [Coordinates of a mouse click on Canvas in Javascript](http://miloq.blogspot.com/2011/05/coordinates-mouse-click-canvas.html). To try the demo, copy the code and paste it into a text editor. Then save it as example.html and, finally, open the file with a browser.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a small modification to [Ryan Artecona's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5932203/1305768) for canvases with a variable (%) width:

```
 HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.relMouseCoords = function (event) {
    var totalOffsetX = 0;
    var totalOffsetY = 0;
    var canvasX = 0;
    var canvasY = 0;
    var currentElement = this;

    do {
        totalOffsetX += currentElement.offsetLeft;
        totalOffsetY += currentElement.offsetTop;
    }
    while (currentElement = currentElement.offsetParent)

    canvasX = event.pageX - totalOffsetX;
    canvasY = event.pageY - totalOffsetY;

    // Fix for variable canvas width
    canvasX = Math.round( canvasX * (this.width / this.offsetWidth) );
    canvasY = Math.round( canvasY * (this.height / this.offsetHeight) );

    return {x:canvasX, y:canvasY}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Be wary while doing the coordinate conversion; there are multiple non-cross-browser values returned in a click event. Using clientX and clientY alone are not sufficient if the browser window is scrolled (verified in Firefox 3.5 and Chrome 3.0).

[This quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html) article provides a more correct function that can use either pageX or pageY or a combination of clientX with document.body.scrollLeft and clientY with document.body.scrollTop to calculate the click coordinate relative to the document origin.

UPDATE: Additionally, offsetLeft and offsetTop are relative to the padded size of the element, not the interior size. A canvas with the padding: style applied will not report the top-left of its content region as offsetLeft. There are various solutions to this problem; the simplest one may be to clear all border, padding, etc. styles on the canvas itself and instead apply them to a box containing the canvas.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what's the point of all these answers that [loop through parent elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5932203/607407) and do all kinds of [weird stuff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_magic).

The `HTMLElement.getBoundingClientRect` method is designed to to handle actual screen position of any element. This includes scrolling, so stuff like `scrollTop` is not needed:

> [**(from MDN)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect) The amount of scrolling that has been done of the viewport area (or
>   **any other scrollable element**) is taken into account when computing the
>   bounding rectangle

#### Normal image

The [very simplest approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20788872/607407) was already posted here. This is correct as long as *no wild CSS* rules are involved.

#### Handling stretched canvas/image

When image pixel width isn't matched by it's CSS width, you'll need to apply some ratio on pixel values:

```
/* Returns pixel coordinates according to the pixel that's under the mouse cursor**/
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.relativeCoords = function(event) {
  var x,y;
  //This is the current screen rectangle of canvas
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  var top = rect.top;
  var bottom = rect.bottom;
  var left = rect.left;
  var right = rect.right;
  //Recalculate mouse offsets to relative offsets
  x = event.clientX - left;
  y = event.clientY - top;
  //Also recalculate offsets of canvas is stretched
  var width = right - left;
  //I use this to reduce number of calculations for images that have normal size 
  if(this.width!=width) {
    var height = bottom - top;
    //changes coordinates by ratio
    x = x*(this.width/width);
    y = y*(this.height/height);
  } 
  //Return as an array
  return [x,y];
}
```

As long as the canvas has no border, [**it works for stretched images (jsFiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/cfzn01c6/).

#### Handling CSS borders

If the canvas has thick border, [the things get little complicated](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/nrw7xu2r/1/). You'll literally need to subtract the border from the bounding rectangle. This can be done using [.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle). This [answer describes the process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27204448/607407).

The function then grows up a little:

```
/* Returns pixel coordinates according to the pixel that's under the mouse cursor**/
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.relativeCoords = function(event) {
  var x,y;
  //This is the current screen rectangle of canvas
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  var top = rect.top;
  var bottom = rect.bottom;
  var left = rect.left;
  var right = rect.right;
  //Subtract border size
  // Get computed style
  var styling=getComputedStyle(this,null);
  // Turn the border widths in integers
  var topBorder=parseInt(styling.getPropertyValue('border-top-width'),10);
  var rightBorder=parseInt(styling.getPropertyValue('border-right-width'),10);
  var bottomBorder=parseInt(styling.getPropertyValue('border-bottom-width'),10);
  var leftBorder=parseInt(styling.getPropertyValue('border-left-width'),10);
  //Subtract border from rectangle
  left+=leftBorder;
  right-=rightBorder;
  top+=topBorder;
  bottom-=bottomBorder;
  //Proceed as usual
  ...
}
```

I can't think of anything that would confuse this final function. See yourself at [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/nrw7xu2r/2/).

#### Notes

If you don't like modifying the native `prototype`s, just change the function and call it with `(canvas, event)` (and replace any `this` with `canvas`).

Answer (score 6):

Here is a very nice tutorial-

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
  function writeMessage(canvas, message) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.font = '18pt Calibri';
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fillText(message, 10, 25);
  }
  function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
      y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
  }
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
    var message = 'Mouse position: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y;
    writeMessage(canvas, message);
  }, false);
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Ryan Artecona's solution didn't work for tablet browsers with zoom.  However this one did.

Comment: Doesn't work with images that have CSS `width`/`height` overriden but still one of the best solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery in 2016, to get click coordinates relative to the canvas, I do:

```
$(canvas).click(function(jqEvent) {
    var coords = {
        x: jqEvent.pageX - $(canvas).offset().left,
        y: jqEvent.pageY - $(canvas).offset().top
    };
});
```

This works since both canvas offset() and jqEvent.pageX/Y are relative to the document regardless of scroll position.

Note that if your canvas is scaled then these coordinates are not the same as canvas **logical coordinates**.  To get those, you would *also* do:

```
var logicalCoords = {
    x: coords.x * (canvas.width / $(canvas).width()),
    y: coords.y * (canvas.height / $(canvas).height())
}
```

Comment: Wow. How does 'jqEvent' become defined? Or 'canvas'? Or in the second example 'coords'? Do you need to run the first example before the second? In that case, why wouldn't you write "to get those, you would ALSO do"? Does this all go in an onclick function or what? Give a little context, mate. And considering the original question was asked in 2008, I think you need to answer in the context of the technology that was available in 2008. Refine your answer using valid jQuery from the version that was available at the time (v1.2). ;)

Comment: OK, sorry for my presumptuousness.  I will edit to remove the that.  I did intend to provide the answer using the most recent frameworks.  And I believe a programmer would not need to be explained what jqEvent, canvas, and coords are.

Comment: Looks good. Thanks for your input! Sorry I gave you a hard time! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend this link-
http://miloq.blogspot.in/2011/05/coordinates-mouse-click-canvas.html

```
<style type="text/css">

  #canvas{background-color: #000;}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

  function init()
  {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", getPosition, false);
  }

  function getPosition(event)
  {
    var x = new Number();
    var y = new Number();
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    if (event.x != undefined && event.y != undefined)
    {
      x = event.x;
      y = event.y;
    }
    else // Firefox method to get the position
    {
      x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft +
          document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop +
          document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }

    x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
    y -= canvas.offsetTop;

    alert("x: " + x + "  y: " + y);
  }

</script>
```

Comment: what is the point of `x = new Number()`? The code below that reassigns `x` which means the Number allocated is just immediately discarded

Answer (score 1):

In Prototype, use cumulativeOffset() to do the recursive summation as mentioned by Ryan Artecona above.

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/cumulativeoffset

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

```
var canvas = yourCanvasElement;
var mouseX = (event.clientX - (canvas.offsetLeft - canvas.scrollLeft)) - 2;
var mouseY = (event.clientY - (canvas.offsetTop - canvas.scrollTop)) - 2;
```

This will give you the exact position of the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 1):

See demo at http://jsbin.com/ApuJOSA/1/edit?html,output .

```
  function mousePositionOnCanvas(e) {
      var el=e.target, c=el;
      var scaleX = c.width/c.offsetWidth || 1;
      var scaleY = c.height/c.offsetHeight || 1;

      if (!isNaN(e.offsetX)) 
          return { x:e.offsetX*scaleX, y:e.offsetY*scaleY };

      var x=e.pageX, y=e.pageY;
      do {
        x -= el.offsetLeft;
        y -= el.offsetTop;
        el = el.offsetParent;
      } while (el);
      return { x: x*scaleX, y: y*scaleY };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was creating an application having a **canvas** over a pdf, that involved a lot of resizes of canvas like Zooming the pdf-in and out, and in turn on every zoom-in/out of PDF I had to resize the canvas to adapt the size of the pdf,  I went through lot of answers in stackOverflow, and didn't found a perfect solution that will eventually solve the problem.

I was using **rxjs** and angular 6, and didn't found any answer specific to the newest version.

Here is the entire code snippet that would be helpful, to anyone leveraging **rxjs** to draw on top of canvas.

```
  private captureEvents(canvasEl: HTMLCanvasElement) {

    this.drawingSubscription = fromEvent(canvasEl, 'mousedown')
      .pipe(
        switchMap((e: any) => {

          return fromEvent(canvasEl, 'mousemove')
            .pipe(
              takeUntil(fromEvent(canvasEl, 'mouseup').do((event: WheelEvent) => {
                const prevPos = {
                  x: null,
                  y: null
                };
              })),

              takeUntil(fromEvent(canvasEl, 'mouseleave')),
              pairwise()
            )
        })
      )
      .subscribe((res: [MouseEvent, MouseEvent]) => {
        const rect = this.cx.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        const prevPos = {
          x: Math.floor( ( res[0].clientX - rect.left ) / ( rect.right - rect.left ) * this.cx.canvas.width ),
          y:  Math.floor( ( res[0].clientY - rect.top ) / ( rect.bottom - rect.top ) * this.cx.canvas.height )
        };
        const currentPos = {
          x: Math.floor( ( res[1].clientX - rect.left ) / ( rect.right - rect.left ) * this.cx.canvas.width ),
          y: Math.floor( ( res[1].clientY - rect.top ) / ( rect.bottom - rect.top ) * this.cx.canvas.height )
        };

        this.coordinatesArray[this.file.current_slide - 1].push(prevPos);
        this.drawOnCanvas(prevPos, currentPos);
      });
  }
```

And here is the snippet that fixes, mouse coordinates relative to size of the canvas, irrespective of how you zoom-in/out the canvas.

```
const prevPos = {
  x: Math.floor( ( res[0].clientX - rect.left ) / ( rect.right - rect.left ) * this.cx.canvas.width ),
  y:  Math.floor( ( res[0].clientY - rect.top ) / ( rect.bottom - rect.top ) * this.cx.canvas.height )
};
const currentPos = {
  x: Math.floor( ( res[1].clientX - rect.left ) / ( rect.right - rect.left ) * this.cx.canvas.width ),
  y: Math.floor( ( res[1].clientY - rect.top ) / ( rect.bottom - rect.top ) * this.cx.canvas.height )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some modifications of the above Ryan Artecona's solution.

```
function myGetPxStyle(e,p)
{
    var r=window.getComputedStyle?window.getComputedStyle(e,null)[p]:"";
    return parseFloat(r);
}

function myGetClick=function(ev)
{
    // {x:ev.layerX,y:ev.layerY} doesn't work when zooming with mac chrome 27
    // {x:ev.clientX,y:ev.clientY} not supported by mac firefox 21
    // document.body.scrollLeft and document.body.scrollTop seem required when scrolling on iPad
    // html is not an offsetParent of body but can have non null offsetX or offsetY (case of wordpress 3.5.1 admin pages for instance)
    // html.offsetX and html.offsetY don't work with mac firefox 21

    var offsetX=0,offsetY=0,e=this,x,y;
    var htmls=document.getElementsByTagName("html"),html=(htmls?htmls[0]:0);

    do
    {
        offsetX+=e.offsetLeft-e.scrollLeft;
        offsetY+=e.offsetTop-e.scrollTop;
    } while (e=e.offsetParent);

    if (html)
    {
        offsetX+=myGetPxStyle(html,"marginLeft");
        offsetY+=myGetPxStyle(html,"marginTop");
    }

    x=ev.pageX-offsetX-document.body.scrollLeft;
    y=ev.pageY-offsetY-document.body.scrollTop;
    return {x:x,y:y};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, as others have said, you need a function to get the [position of the canvas element](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html). Here's a method that's a little more elegant than some of the others on this page (IMHO). You can pass it *any* element and get its position in the document:

```
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = 0, curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

Now calculate the current position of the cursor relative to that:

```
$('#canvas').mousemove(function(e) {
    var pos = findPos(this);
    var x = e.pageX - pos.x;
    var y = e.pageY - pos.y;
    var coordinateDisplay = "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
    writeCoordinateDisplay(coordinateDisplay);
});
```

Notice that I've separated the generic `findPos` function from the event handling code. (*As it should be*. We should try to keep our functions to one task each.)

The values of `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` are relative to `offsetParent`, which could be some wrapper `div` node (or anything else, for that matter). When there is no element wrapping the `canvas` they're relative to the `body`, so there is no offset to subtract. This is why we need to determine the position of the canvas before we can do anything else.

Similary, `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` give the position of the cursor relative to the document. That's why we subtract the canvas's offset from those values to arrive at the true position.

An alternative for *positioned* elements is to directly use the values of `e.layerX` and `e.layerY`. This is less reliable than the method above for two reasons:

1. These values are also relative to the entire document when the event does not take place inside a positioned element
2. They are not part of any standard

Answer (score 0):

ThreeJS r77

```
var x = event.offsetX == undefined ? event.layerX : event.offsetX;
var y = event.offsetY == undefined ? event.layerY : event.offsetY;

mouse2D.x = ( x / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
mouse2D.y = - ( y / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;
```

After trying many solutions. This worked for me. Might help someone else hence posting. Got it from [here](http://www.scriptscoop2.com/t/f93cbd2d95e2/javascript-threejs-issue-with-raycaster-intersection.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified solution (this doesn't work with borders/scrolling):

```
function click(event) {
    const bound = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();

    const xMult = bound.width / can.width;
    const yMult = bound.height / can.height;

    return {
        x: Math.floor(event.offsetX / xMult),
        y: Math.floor(event.offsetY / yMult),
    };
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Hey, this is in dojo, just cause it's what I had the code in already for a project.

It should be fairly Obvious how to convert it back to non dojo vanilla JavaScript.

```
  function onMouseClick(e) {
      var x = e.clientX;
      var y = e.clientY;
  }
  var canvas = dojo.byId(canvasId);
  dojo.connect(canvas,"click",onMouseClick);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: clientX/clientY do not behave similarly across browsers.