# addEventListener in Canvas tag

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dom-events

I have a canvas tag to create a graphic. At each section of my line, I have a "dot" to enable a 'mouseover' and display more detail.

Everything works fine when I don't add an event listener to this dot.

Firebug is warning me:

> s.addEventListener is not a function...

Is it possible to create dynamic event listener? (I'm new to Javascript)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot attach DOM events to things other than DOM objects (elements). The `canvas` is a DOM element, the things you are drawing to the canvas are not. They become a part of the canvas as pixels of an img.

In order to detect a click on a specific point on your canvas you must attach the click event on the canvas element, and then compare the x/y coordinates of the click event with the coordinates of your canvas.

This was answered in: "[How do I get the coordinates of a mouse click on a canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-a-canvas-element)"

Comment: Thank you very much.

I was more interested in creating other canvas in the canvas to add event listener to them but they are not visible (maybe they are behind the main canvas).

Anyway I am now looking for a way to detect the event compare to the mouse position.

Thanks again :-)

Comment: Use the [Easel js framework](http://easeljs.com) this greatly simplifies adding mouse interaction to drawn shapes

Answer (score 4):

If you're gonna be drawing basic structures, I suggest you make use of inline svg.

In this case, all the svg elements become DOM elements and you can attach separate events to each of them.