# HTML5 canvas click event

Tags: html, canvas, click

I made an array of squares

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
for(x=0;x<=25;x++){
  for(y=0;y<=25;y++){   
       ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20); 
  }
}
```

and I want a square to change its colour when clicked. How can I do that?

I don't know much HTML5 and need some help. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532739/addeventlistener-in-canvas-tag

Answer (score 31):

Using jQuery:

First, we determine which cell was clicked, then you could just draw over that rectangle with a different colour:

```
 $("#canvas").click(function(e){

    var x = Math.floor((e.pageX-$("#canvas").offset().left) / 20);
    var y = Math.floor((e.pageY-$("#canvas").offset().top) / 20);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    ctx.fillRect(x*20, y*20, 20, 20);


 });
```

Answer (score 6):

This [beta build](https://github.com/caleb531/jcanvas) by Caleb Evans might help. Following events are included...

- click
- dblclick
- mousedown
- mouseup
- mousemove

Link to demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caleb531/SCNp7/5/).