# Drawing pointer(mouse coordinates) for canvas of HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

I'm having trouble in mouse coordinates when *drawing at canvas* of HTML5. I'm using JavaScript to draw @ canvas.

Here is my current code of locating mouse pointer inside the canvas:

```
$('#canvasID').mousedown(function(e) {   
    // Mouse down location
    var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;   
    var mouseY = e.pageY -
    this.offsetTop;
});
```

Of course my pages has a lot of includes, like I include *header and menu* box.

How can the mouse pointer be precise inside the canvas esp. from different resolution of pc?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/

Comment: I didn't post this as an answer because there is no clear question. Could you explain (in the question) what problem you are having?

Comment: Sir thank you. I already solved the problem. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, here we go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4430498/126584
event.offsetX/Y are not supported in firefox >.<

---

Inside `$('#canvasID').mousedown(function(e) {` e.offsetX and e.offsetY should have the coordinates relative to the top-left corner of the canvas. For a quick and dirty way to see everything in e(vent), dump the contents in a `<div id='debug'>` with

```
$('#canvasID').mousedown(function(e) {
    debug(dump(e));
});

// debug (msg)
function debug (msg) {
    $('#debug').prepend(msg+'<br>\n');
}

// dump(ob)
function dump(ob) {
  var out;
  out = 'Properties:<br>\n';
  for (prop in ob) {
    out = out + prop + ': ' + ob[prop] + '<br>\n';
  }
  return out;
}
```

Long & late answer, just found this as I am playing with canvas right now :-) Hope it still helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

This should return always right location on canvas.

```
$("#canvasID").mouseup(function(e) {
  var offset = $(this).offset();
  var mouseX = e.pageX - offset.left;
  var mouseY = e.pageY - offset.top;
});
```