# What should I use instead of UIEvent.layerX?

Tags: javascript

**UIEvent.layerX is used in the color picker sample code of the following link destination.**

[MDN color picker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas)

But,[UIEvent.layerX is Non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/layerX).

What should I use instead of UIEvent.layerX?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389156/what-substitute-should-we-use-for-layerx-layery-since-they-are-deprecated-in-web

Comment: Thank you for the information. The question was solved.