# Display coordinates value in input text after button clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html

help me with this. I have a javascript to get current user coordinates (latitude & Longitude) by using a botton. So, what I want is when `clicked` the button, it will get the `coordinates` and `display in the two input text` which is one for latitude and one for longitude. Before this, I just display it in `<p>` element.

HTML & PHP:

```
<div class="mb-3"><input class="border rounded-0 form-control" type="text" name="business_latitude" id="" placeholder="Latitude" style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;" value="<?php echo $bizLat; ?>"></div>
<div class="mb-3"><input class="border rounded-0 form-control" type="text" name="business_longitude" id="" placeholder="Longitude" style="font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;" value="<?php echo $bizLong; ?>"></div>
<p id="lati"></p>
<p id="longi"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
var x = document.getElementById("lati");
    var y = document.getElementById("longi");

    function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude;
    y.innerHTML ="Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    }
```

`<?php echo $bizLat; ?>`, `<?php echo $bizLong; ?>` here is where they get saved coordinates in database. I just want to edit the latitude and longitude by pressing the button.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744605/javascript-get-x-and-y-coordinates-on-mouse-click, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979224/insert-mouse-click-coordinates-into-text-input-box-with-javascript, ...

Comment: Where, specifically, are you stuck? Is something not working as you expect? If so, please state your expectation/desire, and what you actually get. Please read "[ask]" for tips & guidelines.

Comment: Duplicate of "[Using an HTML button to call a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1947263/90527)" and likely many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add event listener for a button

```
    const btn = document.getElementById("yourButton");
    const x = document.getElementById("lati");
    const y = document.getElementById("longi");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function onClick(event) {
        document.getElementById("input_latitude").value = x.innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("input_longitude").value = y.innerHTML;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the values of `php` variables using javascript since it run on client side.

You can use `document.cookie` to store values of coordinates and then access them in your `php script`. To store your values in cookie update your js script as:

```js
//declare two variables to store your values
var latitude;
var longitude;
//now assign coordiates to these var in showPosition function or where it is possible.

var x = document.getElementById("lati");
    var y = document.getElementById("longi");

    function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude;
    y.innerHTML ="Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    
    //assigning coordinates
    latitude=position.coords.latitude;
    longitude=position.coords.longitude;
    }
    
    //add a cookie with these variables as
    document.cookie="latitude="+latitude;
    document.cookie="longitude="+longitude;
    
    //to ensure cookies are set
    console.log(document.cookie);
```

Then in `php script`

```html
$latitude = $_COOKIE['latitude'];
$longitude = $_COOKIE['longitude'];
<!--you can use these values to update your database table as well ––>
```