# JavaScript: Getting the right object when handling events

Tags: javascript

So, I have code like this:

```
function Shape() {
  ...
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  ...

  canvas.onmousedown = handleMouseDown;       

}

function handleMouseDown(e) {
  this.width // Doesn't refer to the shape
  // How do I get a reference to the shape here?
}
```

Question - how do I get a reference to the Shape in my event handler?

Comment: HandleMouseDown ? Why would `e` refer to a  shape? You have to create your own functions for handling mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

```
function handleMouseDown(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Then look in web browser console what is inside `e` object. Especially inside `e.target` object.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your event handler code you want to refer to

```
this.width // in function handleMouseDown(e)
```

I wonder what you think this variable should contain. Is it a variable width inside the context of function Shape() ? You did not define it inside the example, so I'm just guessing. What would that be good for anyways ?

I think, if I got it right you want to manage some shapes inside a canvas and want to refer to them in your program. If that is right, I'll try to outline what you may do about this issue.

Get the positions from the mouseclick event: [How do I get the coordinates of a mouse click on a canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-a-canvas-element)

Then with your mouse position relative to your canvas, check against the rectangular areas of your different shapes with your own code.

Make an object for every shape that holds x,y postion and the width/height for every shape in your program.

Add a function to this shapes that can get called by your mouseclick event handler code or just use the coords and other relevant properties of your shapes inside your event handler code to apply any changes.

Answer (score -1):

You can bind `this` inside the function to the `Shape` instance, using [`.bind` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
canvas.onmousedown = handleMouseDown.bind(this);
```

Or if the browser does not support `.bind`, use a closure:

```
var self = this;
canvas.onmousedown = function(event) {
    handleMouseDown.call(self, event);
};
```

But it also means that `this` won't refer to the DOM element anymore. You can access it through `event.target` or `event.currentTarget` though.

Comment: @downvoter: Please explain, otherwise I cannot improve my answer.