# Resize from the area I click

Tags: jquery, css, resize, point, area

I'd like to know if it's possible to resize a content from the area I click instead of the top left default resize.

For example here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/2drYk/29/

```
var $cont = $('.container .content'),
    init_size = $cont.width()*0.1,
    ratio = $cont.width() / $cont.height(),
    c =0,
    s = [400,init_size];

$cont.height( init_size );

$cont.click(function(){   
    $(this).stop().animate({height: s[c%2], width: s[c%2] * ratio });
    c++;
});
```

as you can see it resize from top left to bottom right, Is it possible to set the point it start to resize depending on where I clic ?

Comment: you need to get the location of click. have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-a-canvas-element

Comment: it seems like a none trivial thing.

Comment: Using [d3](http://d3js.org/) would be a good library for everything you want to do, and you wouldn't have to code all that behavior yourself.

Comment: @btevfik I'm not very familiar with canvas, I'm guessing  I should replace my figures with it ?

Comment: @Andrew Mao Thanks! I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: to be honest i am familiar with it either. so i can't help you much. but it was the first thing that came to my mind when you said 'depending on where i click'. you might want to try what Andrew suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you resize, move the image in the proper ratio so that point in the larger image is the same relative point as was the location of the click event.  Essentially this means moving it to negative top and left according to the ratio The calculation for image placement when clicking is:

```
New position = Mouse click event position-New size/Old Size*Mouse click event position
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/adn55/) example

This example makes use of of an equal width/height ratio, but you can easily build upon it to support whichever ratios you require