# Unable to use the full space of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to use the full space of canvas to draw. But here unable to use the top and left of the canvas to draw. I try make some changes in css, still no luck. Please help. 
p.s. By clicking the button the canvas will popup.

```
<button onClick="openPopup();">click here</button>
<div id="test" class="popup">
    <div class="cancel" onclick="closePopup();"></div>
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="750" height="720" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
</div>

<style>
.popup{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width: 900px;
    height: 750px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:13px;
    padding:2px;
    background-color:white;
    border:2px solid grey;
    z-index:100000000000000000;
    display:none;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-top: 90px; 
    overflow: auto; 
    }

.cancel{
    display:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    height:10px;
    width:14px;
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:11px;
    color:white;
    border-radius:3px;
    z-index:100000000000000000;
    }

.cancel:hover{
    background:rgb(255,50,50);
    }
</style>
<script>
function openPopup() {
    document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'block';
}
function closePopup() {
    document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
}

var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
var isPressed = false;
var mx = 4, my = 4;

function move(e) {
  getMouse(e);
  if (isPressed) {
    ctx.lineTo(mx, my);
    ctx.stroke()
  }
}

function up(e) {
  getMouse(e);
  isPressed = false;
}

function down(e) {
  getMouse(e);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(mx, my);
  isPressed = true;
}

can.onmousemove = move;
can.onmousedown = down;
can.onmouseup = up;

// waaaay oversimplified:
function getMouse(e) {
    var element = can, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0;
    mx = e.pageX;
    my = e.pageY;

}

</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Canvas HTML5 real mouse position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130395/canvas-html5-real-mouse-position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drawing point is not synced with mouse pointer.
That is the reason why you can't draw at the left part and the top part of the canvas, because the mouse is already out of the canvas if you try to draw something nearby the left edge.

Notice that how you get the current position of the drawing point:

```
function getMouse(e) {
    var element = can, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0;
    mx = e.pageX;
    my = e.pageY;
}
```

the variable `e` refers to mouseEvent object. and e.pageX means the distance between the mouse  and the left side of the page, NOT YOUR CANVAS. So you should minus the left offset of the canvas from `mx` and do the same to `my`, so that the drawing point is right on where you want.

One simple solution:
set the canvas's `margin`, `border` and `padding` to 0;

```
.popup{
    //everything else..
    boder: 0;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    }
```

Better solution:
minus the left offset to `mx` and `my`

```
function getMouse(e) {
    var element = can, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0;
    mx = e.pageX - 305;
    my = e.pageY - 95;

    //Dynamically getting those padding and margin and border would be better!
}
```