# How to detect touchmove length/offsets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, touch

In developer tools I can see that `touchmove` event is fired multiple times while performing finger move*.

I'm looking for solution that should move `div` on which touchmove is performed - for exact number of touch move pixels, for either one or both axis.

#### What have I done so far?

I've tried to bind anonymous function to `div`'s `touchmove` event, expecting that `e` argument of anonymous function will have something like `offsetX` & `offsetY` like mousemove do, so I could update position parameters of `div` accordingly.

Something like this:

```
$('div').on('touchmove', function(e){
  console.log(e);
  //e has no offset or similar param known to me
});
```

No results.

What should I do instead?

> Special appeal: I will upvote any working solution, but accepted answer goes to the one that will give me at least a starting point about what should I do in plain JavaScript, without abstractions like jQuery mobile.

*
*I'm actually doing cursor touch emulation in Chrome dev tools*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend looking at this article that demonstrates a simple setup for the "touchmove" event and obtaining the offset position in jQuery: http://www.devinrolsen.com/basic-jquery-touchmove-event-setup/

In case the article disappears, here is the code setup with the offset calculated from the event from the article.

```
$('#someElm').bind('touchmove',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
  var elm = $(this).offset();
  var x = touch.pageX - elm.left;
  var y = touch.pageY - elm.top;
});
```

Hopefully this can help find a solution in plain javascript as well.

Comment: seems like that's what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Logged in just to upvote this. There is an alternative solution here that SEEMS "more correct":http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130395/canvas-html5-real-mouse-position, but yours actually works.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a non jQuery solution.

```
function addTouchOffsets (event) {
    var touch = event.touches[0] || event.changedTouches[0];
    var realTarget = document.elementFromPoint(touch.clientX, touch.clientY);
    event.offsetX = touch.clientX-realTarget.getBoundingClientRect().x;
    event.offsetY = touch.clientY-realTarget.getBoundingClientRect().y
    return event;
}
```