# incorrect event.clientY value with ThreeJs raycaster when header bar displayed

Tags: javascript, three.js, coordinates, mouse, raycasting

Here is the problem :

I would like to paste a sphere on a 3D model when I click on it. I use ThreeJs raycaster to do that. It works perfectly if canvas covers the whole page, but not if I add a header bar to the page. Here are some graphic examples :

Without header bar, the sphere appears under mouse pointer, no problem:
[a Ok](http://www.obiz-info.com/ressources/threejs/ok.png)

Now with header bar; oops, the sphere is more downward than mouse pointer:
[a Ko](http://www.obiz-info.com/ressources/threejs/ko_1.png)

If I scroll down the page the problem occurs too, even if there's no header bar.

Here is the js code :

```
function addSphere(coords, color) {

    sphere = new T.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial)

    sphere.position.set(coords.x, coords.y, coords.z)

    sphere.name = 'Sphere'

    scene.add(sphere)

}


function listeners() {

    document.addEventListener('resize', function() {

        var width = window.innerWidth
        var height = window.innerHeight

        camera.aspect = width / height
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
        renderer.setSize(width, height)

    }, false)


    container.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        console.log('Clic sur container')

        e.preventDefault()

        mouse.x = (e.clientX / width) * 2 - 1
        mouse.y = - (e.clientY / height) * 2 + 1

        ray.setFromCamera(mouse, camera)

        var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(scene.children)

        if ( intersects[0].object.name == 'Mannequin' ) {

            // var coords = mannequin.worldToLocal(intersects[0].point)
            var coords = intersects[0].point

            addSphere(coords, 'color')

            console.log('Clic sur le mannequin')
            console.log(intersects[0])

        }

        if ( intersects[0].object.name == 'Sphere' ) {

            console.log('Clique sur la sphère : ', intersects[0].object)

        }

    }, false)

}
```

And index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- <script src="js/app.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="js/exemple.js"></script> -->

</head>
<body>

    <div id="header-bar" style="left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; height: 44px; line-height: 44px; text-align: center; font-size: 1.4em">Header bar</div>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <div id="buttons" style="display: block; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; height: 25px;">

        <button id="btnFront">Front</button>
        <button id="btnBack">Back</button>
        <button id="btnRight">Right</button>
        <button id="btnIso1">Iso 1</button>
        <button id="btnIso2">iso 2</button>
        <button id="btnFeet">Feet</button>
        <button id="btnDelete">Delete</button>
        <button id="btnUndo">Undo</button>
        <button id="btnRotation">Rotation on/off</button>

    </div>

    <!-- Three.js -->
    <script src="lib/threejs/three.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/threejs/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="lib/threejs/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/threejs/Projector.js"></script> -->

    <script src="js/mannequin.js"></script>
    <script src="js/events.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand what happens. Anyone has an idea ?

Thank you by advance.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [so]! Please give a [mcve] for the community to be able to help!

Comment: Please add your images to imgur.com, ideally through the image upload system in Stack Overflow. Images to your own web server are discouraged, since they are likely to break over time.

Comment: ok, I'll do that next time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing 44 units from e.clientY (44 is the height of the header bar).

```
mouse.x = (e.clientX / width) * 2 - 1
mouse.y = - ((e.clientY - 44) / height) * 2 + 1
```

But if I scroll the page the problem persists.

Comment: Probably, it's because you set the size of a renderer without counting that its height must be 44 pixels lesser. Also, you don't count it in your `resize` listener. If you count it, then you won't need `- 44` in `e.clietnY - 44`.

Answer (score 0):

@prisoner849 Thank you for your answer. it led me to these links :

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates

&

[Real mouse position in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130395/real-mouse-position-in-canvas)

I tried:

```
function getMousePositionInCanvas(canvas, e) {

    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
    return {
        x: e.clientX - rect.left,
        y: e.clientY - rect.top
    }

}


    var mousePosInCanvas = getMousePositionInCanvas(document.querySelector('canvas'), e)

    mouse.x = (mousePosInCanvas.x / width) * 2 - 1
    mouse.y = - (mousePosInCanvas.y / height) * 2 + 1
```

And it works perfectly.

Thank you very much !