# Touch events on canvas in javascript have wrong coordinates

Tags: javascript, event-handling, html5-canvas, touchscreen

I have an html5 canvas game for desktop browsers that uses the keyboard, and I'm trying to create compatibility for smartphones by adding touch-screen controls.

The current issue is that the events for touch input are returning X and Y coordinates that don't match the location where I'm touching.

[image: screenshot from my game]

The purple dots in the image above are a diagnostic test I added.  The game places a circle in each location where it detects a touch event.  In this case, I traced the border of my phone screen.  The placement of dots illustrates the difference between where my screen actually is and where the game seems to think it is.

```
<body onload="html_init()">
  <div class="canvas_div" id="canvas_div">
    <canvas width="1050" height="600" id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>

function html_init()
  {
  canvas_html = document.getElementById ("canvas");
  window.addEventListener ("resize", resize_canvas, false);
  canvas_html.addEventListener ("touchstart",  function(event) {touch_start (event)},  false);
  }

function resize_canvas ()
  {
  // Scale to fit window, decide which scaling reaches edge first.

  canvas_2d.restore();
  canvas_2d.save();

  var game_ratio = canvas_2d.canvas.width / canvas_2d.canvas.height;
  var window_ratio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  var xratio = window.innerWidth / canvas_2d.canvas.width;
  var yratio = window.innerHeight / canvas_2d.canvas.height;

  var ratio;
  if (game_ratio > window_ratio) ratio = xratio;
  else ratio = yratio;
  if (ratio > 1) ratio = 1;

  canvas_2d.scale (ratio, ratio);
  }

function touch_start (event)
  {
  var touch = event.changedTouches;
  var x = touch[0].pageX;
  var y = touch[0].pageY;

  // this goes on to add the purple test sprite to the screen at that location.
  }
```

I've tried referencing pageX, clientX and screenX, but none of them have the correct values.  Even though my canvas is set to 1050 x 600, which is what my game runs at, the touch screen seems to think it's somewhere around 650 x 350.  If it matters, the test phone is an iPhone 6.

I'm not sure what to check at this point.  Any ideas are appreciated.

**UPDATE**: I've narrowed the problem down to two facts - that the canvas size is larger than the display area of the web page being shown, and that I'm using resize_canvas() to set the scale.  It looks like I'm going to have to either reduce the overall size of the canvas to fit the phone or add a formulaic adjustment to the coordinates based on the scale ratio.

Comment: Please paste the HTML. Canvas usually takes height and width properties that describe it's size. Could you check it you don't have wrong values supplied there?

Comment: @MartinChaov: I've pasted my html.  Everything there looks correct to me.

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130395/real-mouse-position-in-canvas/17130415#17130415) with the touch events.

Comment: @K3N: That's a good idea, but my canvas is always at (0, 0).  I used absolute positioning.

Comment: @NightmareGames it also covers scaled canvas

Answer (score 1):

```
canvas_html.addEventListener ("touchstart", touch_start,  false);

function resize_canvas ()
  {
  // Scale to fit window, decide which scaling reaches edge first.

  canvas_2d.restore();
  canvas_2d.save();

  var current_ratio = canvas_2d.canvas.width / canvas_2d.canvas.height;
  var new_ratio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  var xratio = window.innerWidth / canvas_2d.canvas.width;
  var yratio = window.innerHeight / canvas_2d.canvas.height;

  if (current_ratio > new_ratio) screen_size_ratio = xratio;
  else screen_size_ratio = yratio;
  if (screen_size_ratio > 1) screen_size_ratio = 1;

  canvas_2d.scale (screen_size_ratio, screen_size_ratio);
  }

function touch_start (event)
  {
  var touch = event.changedTouches;
  var x = Math.floor (touch[0].clientX / screen_size_ratio);
  var y = Math.floor (touch[0].clientY / screen_size_ratio);
  }
```

Because of the scale() I was doing on the canvas, the actual coordinates had to be un-scaled using the ratio I calculated in canvas_resize().

I also had to change my "touchstart" event handler to not use an anonymous function.  For whatever reason, this was causing the phone browser to default back to using "mousedown" for the click.