# How to Fix Mouse position relative to parent of canvas?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, vue-component

I am trying to use the Vuejs Draw Canvas of this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Lewitje/pen/MVommB) as a component. Everything works great but the mouse position is relative to the window I think. So when drawn it works perfectly fine only if the canvas is window size ( width, height) if not there is a huge difference in the cursor and draw position.

I have tried setting the canvas width and height to offset instead of window like

```
setSize() {
   this.c.width = this.c.offsetWidth;
   this.c.height = this.c.offsetHeight - 60;
}
```

and mouse positions with below code as in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130395/real-mouse-position-in-canvas) answers

```
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: (evt.clientX - rect.left) / (rect.right - rect.left) * canvas.width,
        y: (evt.clientY - rect.top) / (rect.bottom - rect.top) * canvas.height
    };
}
```

but it did not change the result. So reverted back and added in code sandbox. If anyone can help me find out what the issue here? I know it's with mouse position but not sure exactly where.

**Here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-qqpfr) link of the demo im trying to fix.**

Answer (score 0):

I use these two methods (not sure without further digging why they are not the same):

```
canv = document.getElementById("id-of-canvas-object")

function mouseLocation(e)
{
 if (e.preventDefault)
    e.preventDefault();
 var x = e.PageX; var y = e.PageY;
// in one instance
 var relativeX = x - canv.offsetLeft;
 var relativeY = y - canv.offsetTop;
// in another instance
  var rect = canv.getBoundingClientRect();
  relativeX = x - rect.left;
  relativeY = y - rect.top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the example you shared you are not taking in count the offset when re positioning the cursor and you're substracting a 60px offset that is unnecessary because of the fixed positioning of the controls.

There are just 2 differences on lines: 234 & 239

```
setSize() {
  this.c.width = this.c.offsetWidth;
  this.c.height = this.c.offsetHeight; // <--- HERE i removed the -60px offset
}

moveMouse(e) {
  let x = e.offsetX;
  let y = e.offsetY + 60; // <--- HERE i added the 60px offset
  // the ´e.offsetY´ is relative to the canvas but you have an offset
  // for the controls that is moving the cursor (the little dot) to the top

  var cursor = document.getElementById("cursor");

  cursor.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`;
}
```

Heres the example fixed: [Fixed codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-xzywy)

Note: I recommend to change the fixed positioning of the controls and manage everything with fixed height and width values or use flexbox to grow the canvas as it needs to.