# Why doesn't HTML Canvas let me utilise the whole drawing space?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi this might seem a basic question, but let me just ask it anyway:

I am trying to develop a scribbling tool with html, css & javascript. I have a canvas which I upload an image to, and draw lines on. When I place the canvas element within a div, I cannot use the whole space to draw (Screenshot 1), but when I place the canvas element separately and as the top most element on the page I can utilise the whole drawing space. I am not sure what is going on but please CSS and Js stalwarts out there if you could tell me what I am doing wrong (or how to solve this issue)?[image: Screenshot1][image: Screenshot2]

Also the html code is written below

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Another day... Another app</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
        <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div id="main" class="main">
        
            <input type="text" placeholder="search notes.. ">
            <a href="javascript:void(null);" onclick="openOverlay();">Create note</a>
            
        </div>
        
        <div id="overlay" class="overlay">
            <a href="javascript:void(null);" onclick="closeOverlay();">Close &times;</a>
            <div id="overlay-content" class="overlay-content">
                <div class="top" id="top">
                    <label for="note">Notes</label>
                    <textarea id="note"></textarea>
                </div>
                
<!--                <div class="middle" id="middle">-->
                    
<!--                </div>-->
                 <div class="bottom" id="bottom">
                     <label for="note">Notes</label>
                    <textarea id="note"></textarea>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="560"></canvas>
        
    
        
    </body>
</html>
```

The css is written below:

```
*{
    
    
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

body{
    
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1px;
    
}

body a{
    
    font-size: 10em;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 4em;
    
}


body input[type=text]{
    font-size: 20em;
    display: block;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(252,186,1);
  background-color: rgba(252,186,1, 0.9);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content{
    
    margin: 20em;
    padding: 10em;
    display: block;
}

#top, #bottom{
    padding: 40em;
}


/*
.overlay-content label{
    font-size: 20em;
    display: block;
}

.overlay-content label{
    font-size: 20em;
    display: block;
}

.overlay-content canvas-ctr{
    display: block;
}
*/




@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  
    
}
```

EDIT: here's the JS I use:

```
function openOverlay() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.width = "100%";
    
//     initNote(); 
    
    
}

function closeOverlay() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.width = "0%";
}



//function initNote(){
//    
    
        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        const img = new Image();
        img.src = "assets/images/Img.JPG";

        img.onload = () => {
            const [img_scaled_width, img_scaled_height] = drawImageToScale(img, ctx);
            canvas.width = img_scaled_width;
            canvas.height = img_scaled_height;
            window.addEventListener('resize', drawImageToScale(img,ctx));

        }

        // variables
        let painting = false;

        function startPosition(e){
            painting = true;
            draw(e);
        }

        function finishedPosition(){
            painting = false;
            ctx.beginPath();
        }

        function draw(e){
            if (!painting)
                return;
            ctx.lineWidth = 3;

            ctx.lineCap = 'round';

            //console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);

            ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        }

        // eventListeners
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", finishedPosition);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw)
    });
    
    const MAX_WIDTH=400;
    const MAX_HEIGHT=560;

    function drawImageToScale(img, ctx){
        
        var img_width = MAX_WIDTH;
        var img_height = MAX_HEIGHT;
        
        const scaleFactor = img_width / img.width;
        if(img.height < MAX_HEIGHT){
           const img_height = img.height * scaleFactor;
        }
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,img_width,img_height); 
        return [img_width,img_height];
        
    }

    
    
    
    
    
//}
```

Comment: If you posted some JS it may help people help you

Comment: had you tried giving the padding and margin to 0?

Comment: `client`X or Y are relative to the viewport, the drawing methods are relative to the canvas context's transform matrix (in your case, to the canvas bitmap)

Comment: @Uttam I might have toggled out with the margin and padding but did not help.

Comment: @Kaiido on researching a little after your comment, I came across the bounding client rect property and looks like might solve the issue https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect I will try and post the result if successful.

Comment: All you need is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130395/real-mouse-position-in-canvas No need to add yet an other answer.