# HTML canvas shooting game: not shooting where I click and not linked when moving the player

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas, event-listener

I'm creating a canvas game and I'm working on the shooting aspect of the game. I've created a player that can move and a shooting function but I have two issues:

1. I would like to click in the canvas and have a projectile send to the click location. What is happening is that the click trigger location is disconnected from the canvas so that if I click around the top left of the page I can aim where I shoot.
2. I have have enabled movement with the player but I'm not sure how to link the movement of the player and update the origin of the projectile. I have set up movement functions for both player and projectile but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

https://codepen.io/blacksunmachine/pen/mdmxLxg

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = innerWidth / 2; // this takes up the whole page horizontally
canvas.height = innerHeight / 2; // this takes up the whole page verticallly

class Player {
  constructor(x, y, radius, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;
  }
  draw() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.fill();
  }
  moveLeft() {
    this.x -= 30;
    if (this.x <= 0) {
      this.x = 0;
    }
  }
  moveRight() {
    this.x += 30;
    if (this.x >= canvas.width) {
      this.x = canvas.width;
    }
  }
  moveUp() {
    this.y -= 30;
    if (this.y <= 0) {
      this.y = 0;
    }
  }
  moveDown() {
    this.y += 30;
    if (this.y >= canvas.height) {
      this.y = canvas.height;
    }
  }
}
// player position
let newPlayer1 = new Player(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 10, "blue");

class Projectile {
  constructor(x, y, radius, color, velocity) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;
    this.velocity = velocity;
  }
  draw() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.fill();
  }
  update() {
    this.draw();
    this.x = this.x + this.velocity.x;
    this.y = this.y + this.velocity.y;
  }
  moveLeft() {
    this.x -= 30;
    if (this.x <= 0) {
      this.x = 0;
    }
  }
  moveRight() {
    this.x += 30;
    if (this.x >= canvas.width) {
      this.x = canvas.width;
    }
  }
  moveUp() {
    this.y -= 30;
    if (this.y <= 0) {
      this.y = 0;
    }
  }
  moveDown() {
    this.y += 30;
    if (this.y >= canvas.height) {
      this.y = canvas.height;
    }
  }
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  newPlayer1.draw();

  projectiles.forEach((projectile) => {
    projectile.update();
  });
}

const projectile = new Projectile(
  canvas.width / 2,
  canvas.height / 2,
  10,
  "red",
  {
    x: -1,
    y: -1,
  }
);

const projectiles = [];


// need to link shooting with movement of the character

addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    console.log(event)
    const angle = Math.atan2(
    event.clientY - canvas.height / 2,
    event.clientX - canvas.width / 2
  ); // detemine direction of click
  console.log(angle); // show where is being clicked
  const velocity = {
    // speed and direction of click
    x: Math.cos(angle) * 20,
    y: Math.sin(angle) * 20,
  };
  // from original position (in the middle of the screen) move a projectile with velocity
  projectiles.push(
    new Projectile(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 10, "red", velocity)
  );
});

// difference in X and Y when moving the character - not using this at the moment
// let deltaX = 0;
// let deltaY = 0;

// movement keys for player 1
window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
function handleKeyDown(event) {
  switch (
    event.keyCode // position of letters might change when on different layouts - same in every language
  ) {
    case 37: // left
      newPlayer1.moveLeft();
         projectile.moveLeft()
      break;

    case 38: // up
      newPlayer1.moveUp();
      projectile.moveUp()
      break;

    case 39: // right
      newPlayer1.moveRight();
        projectile.moveRight()
      break;

    case 40: // down
      newPlayer1.moveDown();
      projectile.moveDown()
      break;

    default:
      console.log("you cannot move player 1 like that");
  }
  console.log(event);
}

animate();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Real mouse position in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130395/real-mouse-position-in-canvas)

Comment: That's really helpful, thank @Billy Brown!

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code of what i understood in your question.**

```
canvas.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    try{
        let x=e.clientX;
        let y=e.clientY;
        let angle=Math.atan2(y-player.y-(player.rad/2),x-player.x-(player.rad/2));
        x=player.x+(player.rad/2);
        y=player.y+(player.rad/2);
        let vx=Math.cos(angle)*15;
        let vy=Math.sin(angle)*15;
        projectileArray.push(new Projectile(x,y,vx,vy));
    }catch(e){}
});
```

**Variables explaination**

1. **player.rad** is the radius of player
2. Here **player** is the object of the Player class
3. This function fires when you click on the canvas
4. The **15** value which i added in the **line 8 and 9 of my code** is just the **velocity** of the bullet
5. **new Projectile(x,y,cx,vy)** is the bullet which takes the current x, y position which  is the players position and vx, vy after resolving the components of x and y of the click position from the player
6. **projectileArray** is just an array containing the bullets fired for rendering all of the bullets on the canvas

**Actually this code is what i created for making my own shooting game. If you want to see how it works just click on this link to play it.**
[Shooter Game](https://o35f2rf0mlls3z6zrf72za-on.drv.tw/www.shootergame.com/)

**This link is provided strictly for you to understand how it works and not for publicising my game.**

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code Ruthvik! interesting alternative to my code and your game looks cool!