# Player-Centered Webgame: Aiming Precision Issues with ctx.setTransform

Tags: javascript, game-development

I'm making a webgame and i want to keep the player at the center of the screen. But the further the player gets from the center the less accurate it gets. I'm tried using ctx.setTransform, but while that works fine for the movement it breaks the aiming. to make the problem obvious i added a red dot where the player is aiming.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvasWidth = canvas.width;
canvasHeight = canvas.height;



function draw(posX, posY, width, height, color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(posX, posY, width, height);
}
class Player {
  constructor(width, height, color) {
    this.posX = canvasWidth / 2;
    this.posY = canvasHeight / 2;
    this.width = width || 32;
    this.height = height || 32;
    this.color = color || "red";
    this.speed = 4; // lower is faster
    this.velocity = [0, 0];
    this.keys = {
      w: false,
      a: false,
      s: false,
      d: false,
    };
    this.bullets = [];
    this.lastShotTime = 0;
    this.fireRate = 750; // lower is faster
    this.gunWidth = 22;
    this.gunHeight = 10;
    this.gunColor = "black";
    this.gunAngle = 0;
  }

  position() {
    if (this.keys["a"]) {
      if (this.velocity[0] > -this.speed) {
        this.velocity[0] -= 0.5;
      }
    }
    if (this.keys["d"]) {
      if (this.velocity[0] < this.speed) {
        this.velocity[0] += 0.5;
      }
    }
    if (this.keys["w"]) {
      if (this.velocity[1] > -this.speed) {
        this.velocity[1] -= 0.5;
      }
    }
    if (this.keys["s"]) {
      if (this.velocity[1] < this.speed) {
        this.velocity[1] += 0.5;
      }
    }
    
    if (this.firing) {
      this.shoot();
    }

    this.posX += this.velocity[0];
    this.posY += this.velocity[1];
    if (this.keys["a"] === false && this.keys["d"] === false) {
      this.velocity[0] *= 0.9;
    }
    if (this.keys["w"] === false && this.keys["s"] === false) {
      this.velocity[1] *= 0.9;
    }
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.arc(this.posX, this.posY, this.width / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();

    // Draw the rotated gun
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.translate(this.posX, this.posY);
    ctx.rotate(this.gunAngle);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.gunColor;
    ctx.fillRect(0, -this.gunHeight / 2, this.gunWidth, this.gunHeight);
    ctx.restore();
  }

  shoot() {
    const currentTime = Date.now();
    if (currentTime - this.lastShotTime < this.fireRate) {
      return;
    }
    shoot();
    function shoot() {
      const bullet = new Bullet(
        player.posX + player.width / 10,
        player.posY + player.height / 10,
        player.gunAngle
      );
      player.bullets.push(bullet);
    }
    this.lastShotTime = currentTime;
  }
}

class Bullet {
  constructor(posX, posY, angle) {
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.speed = 15;
    this.angle = angle;
    this.width = 10;
    this.height = 10;
    this.color = "green";
  }
  move() {
    this.posX += this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);
    this.posY += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
  }
  draw() {
    draw(this.posX, this.posY, this.width, this.height, this.color);
  }
}

var player = new Player();

update();
function update() {
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

  transformX = -player.posX + canvasWidth / 2;
  transformY = -player.posY + canvasHeight / 2;
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, transformX, transformY);

  if (player.firing) {
    player.shoot();
  }

  player.bullets.forEach((bullet) => {
    bullet.move();
    bullet.draw();
  });

  // remove bullets when it leaves the canvas
  player.bullets = player.bullets.filter(
    (bullet) =>
      bullet.posX >= 0 &&
      bullet.posX <= canvasWidth &&
      bullet.posY >= 0 &&
      bullet.posY <= canvasHeight
  );

  draw(lastMouseX, lastMouseY, 20, 20, "red");

  player.position();
  player.draw();

  aim(lastMouseX, lastMouseY);
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  player.keys[e.key.toLowerCase()] = true;
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
  player.keys[e.key.toLowerCase()] = false;
});
var lastMouseX = 0;
var lastMouseY = 0;
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  lastMouseX = e.clientX;
  lastMouseY = e.clientY;
});
function aim(lastMouseX, lastMouseY) {
  var angle = Math.atan2(lastMouseY - player.posY, lastMouseX - player.posX);
  player.gunAngle = angle;
}
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
  player.firing = true;
});
document.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
  player.firing = false;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <script src="minscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the "real mouse position" is not selected in the canvas.

Have a look at this post [Real mouse position in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130395/real-mouse-position-in-canvas)

With this change, the canvas (relative to the window) is taken into account:

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  var bound = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  lastMouseX = event.clientX - bound.left - canvas.clientLeft;
  lastMouseY = event.clientY - bound.top - canvas.clientTop;
});
```

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvasWidth = canvas.width;
canvasHeight = canvas.height;



function draw(posX, posY, width, height, color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(posX, posY, width, height);
}
class Player {
  constructor(width, height, color) {
    this.posX = canvasWidth / 2;
    this.posY = canvasHeight / 2;
    this.width = width || 32;
    this.height = height || 32;
    this.color = color || "red";
    this.speed = 4; // lower is faster
    this.velocity = [0, 0];
    this.keys = {
      w: false,
      a: false,
      s: false,
      d: false,
    };
    this.bullets = [];
    this.lastShotTime = 0;
    this.fireRate = 750; // lower is faster
    this.gunWidth = 22;
    this.gunHeight = 10;
    this.gunColor = "black";
    this.gunAngle = 0;
  }

  position() {
    if (this.keys["a"]) {
      if (this.velocity[0] > -this.speed) {
        this.velocity[0] -= 0.5;
      }
    }
    if (this.keys["d"]) {
      if (this.velocity[0] < this.speed) {
        this.velocity[0] += 0.5;
      }
    }
    if (this.keys["w"]) {
      if (this.velocity[1] > -this.speed) {
        this.velocity[1] -= 0.5;
      }
    }
    if (this.keys["s"]) {
      if (this.velocity[1] < this.speed) {
        this.velocity[1] += 0.5;
      }
    }
    
    if (this.firing) {
      this.shoot();
    }

    this.posX += this.velocity[0];
    this.posY += this.velocity[1];
    if (this.keys["a"] === false && this.keys["d"] === false) {
      this.velocity[0] *= 0.9;
    }
    if (this.keys["w"] === false && this.keys["s"] === false) {
      this.velocity[1] *= 0.9;
    }
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.arc(this.posX, this.posY, this.width / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();

    // Draw the rotated gun
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.translate(this.posX, this.posY);
    ctx.rotate(this.gunAngle);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.gunColor;
    ctx.fillRect(0, -this.gunHeight / 2, this.gunWidth, this.gunHeight);
    ctx.restore();
  }

  shoot() {
    const currentTime = Date.now();
    if (currentTime - this.lastShotTime < this.fireRate) {
      return;
    }
    shoot();
    function shoot() {
      const bullet = new Bullet(
        player.posX + player.width / 10,
        player.posY + player.height / 10,
        player.gunAngle
      );
      player.bullets.push(bullet);
    }
    this.lastShotTime = currentTime;
  }
}

class Bullet {
  constructor(posX, posY, angle) {
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.speed = 15;
    this.angle = angle;
    this.width = 10;
    this.height = 10;
    this.color = "green";
  }
  move() {
    this.posX += this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);
    this.posY += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
  }
  draw() {
    draw(this.posX, this.posY, this.width, this.height, this.color);
  }
}

var player = new Player();

update();
function update() {
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

  transformX = -player.posX + canvasWidth / 2;
  transformY = -player.posY + canvasHeight / 2;
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, transformX, transformY);

  if (player.firing) {
    player.shoot();
  }

  player.bullets.forEach((bullet) => {
    bullet.move();
    bullet.draw();
  });

  // remove bullets when it leaves the canvas
  player.bullets = player.bullets.filter(
    (bullet) =>
      bullet.posX >= 0 &&
      bullet.posX <= canvasWidth &&
      bullet.posY >= 0 &&
      bullet.posY <= canvasHeight
  );

  draw(lastMouseX, lastMouseY, 20, 20, "red");

  player.position();
  player.draw();

  aim(lastMouseX, lastMouseY);
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  player.keys[e.key.toLowerCase()] = true;
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
  player.keys[e.key.toLowerCase()] = false;
});
var lastMouseX = 0;
var lastMouseY = 0;
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  var bound = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  lastMouseX = event.clientX - bound.left - canvas.clientLeft;
  lastMouseY = event.clientY - bound.top - canvas.clientTop;
});
function aim(lastMouseX, lastMouseY) {
  var angle = Math.atan2(lastMouseY - player.posY, lastMouseX - player.posX);
  player.gunAngle = angle;
}
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
  player.firing = true;
});
document.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
  player.firing = false;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <script src="minscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```