# canvas get points on mouse events

Tags: jquery, canvas, mouseevent, coordinates

I am having the following function to get the mouse click positions(coordinates).

```
$('#myCanvas').on('click', function(e) {
    event = e;
    event = event || window.event;

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
            x = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft,
            y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    alert(x + ' ' + y);
});
```

I need to get the mouse point on clicking a position and also secound mouse point position after draging the same.

ie.,
mousedown point and mouseup points.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the coordinates of a mouse click on a canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-a-canvas-element)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try a little different setup:

```
var canvas = myCanvas;  //store canvas outside event loop
var isDown = false;     //flag we use to keep track
var x1, y1, x2, y2;     //to store the coords

// when mouse button is clicked and held    
$('#myCanvas').on('mousedown', function(e){
    if (isDown === false) {

        isDown = true;

        var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
        x1 = pos.x;
        y1 = pos.y;
    }
});

// when mouse button is released (note: window, not canvas here)
$(window).on('mouseup', function(e){

    if (isDown === true) {

        var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
        x2 = pos.x;
        y2 = pos.y;

        isDown = false;

        //we got two sets of coords, process them
        alert(x1 + ',' + y1 + ',' +x2 + ',' +y2);
    }
});

// get mouse pos relative to canvas (yours is fine, this is just different)
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}
```

So why do we listen to mouse up on the `window`? If you mouse outside the `canvas` and then release the mouse button, the event won't be registered with the `canvas`. So we need to listen to a global event such as the `window`.

Since we already have marked our `isDown` at the mouse down event we know that that the following mouse up "belongs" to the canvas (as we check the `isDown` flag).

Answer (score 0):

use receivers like $('#myCanvas').mousedown and $('#myCanvas').mouseup

Answer (score 0):

So, you need drag'n'drop? Well, it's very easy: first you detect 'onclick' if point inside of your target (rect, circle, whatever) save point to variable , 'onmousemove' you're moving the object and then 'onmousedown' you're getting last point.

Hope it will help you!