# element.offsetTop appears incorrect in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to find a click location in a canvas.

I successfully get the Y position on the screen and add the document.body.scrollTop.
I then need to subtract the canvas.offsetTop.

However, that does not point to the top of the canvas element, but to the bottom of the document.

This is true in both FF and Chrome.

Can someone tell me the magic variable I need to tell me the actual offset of an element in the document?

Comment: Create a jsFiddle of your code, with both html and javascript. Otherwise is going to be extremely difficult to help you.

Comment: No repro: http://jsfiddle.net/Q833L/

Comment: Any help? [`offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetTop), [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollTop) and [`offsetParent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetParent).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the coordinates of a mouse click on a canvas element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-a-canvas-element)