# Add click event to the Image on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have created a canvas and added an image on it. I want to add a click event to that image. Below is my code for the same.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="1000"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  //This code is for adding leftArrow icon
  var leftArrow = new Image();
  leftArrow.src = "leftArrow.jpg";

  leftArrow.addEventListener("click",function(){alert("hello");},false); //this is not working

  leftArrow.onclick=function(){alert("image click");}

    drawScreen();


  function drawScreen() {
    //context.drawImage(leftArrow, 218, 482);//leftArrow
    leftArrow.onload = function(){
              context.drawImage(leftArrow, 218, 482);
    }
  }

</script>
```

I want to add event to its click.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I have seen the links and found the answers are not satisfactory. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the *click* event on the `leftArrow`. When you draw the `leftArrow` on the `canvas`, your copying *image contents*, not *events*.

In fact, `new Image()` is about the same as `document.createElement("img")` - you get a `<img ...>`.

So, to assign click event to the canvas, you have to do this:

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", function() {alert("click");});
```

If you only want to check whether the click is within a rectangle where the arrow is, you will need to get the click offsets and calculate it:

```
var x,y; //Click offsets, here I assume they already have the value
var posx, posy; //Position of the arrow, the values you used as .drawImage parameters
var endx = posx + leftArrow.width;
var endy = posy + leftArrow.height;
if( (x>posx && y>posy) && (x<endx && y<endy) )
   alert("Arrow was clicked!");
```

Aditionally, **never** assign `onload` to image *after* you set up the `src` attribute. The image loads asynchronously and there's a possibility that it loads *before* you set up the `onload` event.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, But I want the click event to happen only when I click on the Image but not on the entire canvas.

Comment: There's no `Image` on that canvas. The whole `canvas` is one image. The only thing you can do is to use the [click coordinates on that canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4430498/607407) to calculate whether it's on the arrow or not. By using canvas rendering you're basically throwing away all the benefits of DOM.

Comment: So i have to again find the coordinates of where the click happened on canvas and if coordinates match that of the Image I add my function there. Is it?

Comment: Yes. I strongly suggest you try to render arrow as separate HTML element. Did you know that [SVG images can be animated using JavaScript](http://u8.8u.cz/pokus.svg)?