# To get x,y coordinate of event on Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to find out the x and y coordinates of a click event on Google Map. This X and Y coordinates should be with respect to screen or page.

Comment: I mean, if you need a coordinate in respect to the window (or screen) than you having a Goog map, or a hot potato, makes no difference.

Comment: Here is a link how to get coordinates - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-a-canvas-element. As Roko mentioned Google Maps are not related to it.

Comment: yes the map is 100% x 100% , and i just want to get the coordinate of the point of click on google map  and yes it should be with respect to screen.  My code is little complex and its difficult to put the whole set to codes.
Thanks for the reply man @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: @SumitSagar well, have you tested my example?

Answer (score 0):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/zorohimeni/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

```
mapCanvas.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    var r = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = e.clientX - r.left;
    var y = e.clientY - r.top;
    console.log(x, y);
});
```