# Get the mouse coordinates when clicking on canvas

Tags: canvas, coordinates, mouse

A common question, but I still need help. I'm trying to get and store the mouse coordinates when someone clicks within the canvas.

my HTML

```
<canvas id="puppyCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:2px solid black" onclick = "storeGuess(event)"></canvas>
```

and my javascript

```
//setup canvas
var canvasSetup = document.getElementById("puppyCanvas");
var ctx = canvasSetup.getContext("2d");

guessX = 0;//stores user's click on canvas
 guessY = 0;//stores user's click on canvas

function storeGuess(event){
    var x = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
    /*guessX = x;
    guessY = y;*/


    console.log("x coords:" + x + ", y coords" + y);
```

I've read loads of forums, w3schools, and videos on this. I'm close to figuring it out, but I'm missing something. I can get the coordinates of the page if I delete the ctx.canvas.offsetLeft and ctx.canvas.offsetTop. But i need to incorporate those somehow to get the coordinates of the canvas, and then store then into the variables guessX and guessY.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the coordinates of a mouse click on a canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-a-canvas-element)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could achieve that by using the [**`offsetX`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX) and [**`offsetY`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetY) property of `MouseEvent`

```js
//setup canvas
var canvasSetup = document.getElementById("puppyCanvas");
var ctx = canvasSetup.getContext("2d");
guessX = 0; //stores user's click on canvas
guessY = 0; //stores user's click on canvas
function storeGuess(event) {
    var x = event.offsetX;
    var y = event.offsetY;
    guessX = x;
    guessY = y;
    console.log("x coords: " + guessX + ", y coords: " + guessY);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="puppyCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:2px solid black" onclick="storeGuess(event)"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using this piece of code.

```js
var myCanvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');

myCanvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var rect = myCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
    var y = event.clientY - rect.top;
    console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y); 
}, false);
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="canvas" style="background-color: lightblue"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43172344/3102264) is correct till the canvas is not fit inside a content.

A more generic solution need to convert mouse event in the canvas geometry.

```js
const canvasSetup = document.getElementById("puppyCanvas");
const ctx = canvasSetup.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.lineWidth = 3;

guessX = 0; //stores user's click on canvas
guessY = 0; //stores user's click on canvas
function storeGuess(event) {
    guessX = parseInt(event.offsetX*canvasSetup.width/canvasSetup.offsetWidth);
    guessY = parseInt(event.offsetY*canvasSetup.height/canvasSetup.offsetHeight);
    console.log(`coords:${guessX}x${guessY}`);
    ctx.strokeRect(guessX,guessY,1,1);
}
```

```html
<div style="height:200px;">
<canvas id="puppyCanvas" style="background-color: lightgrey;height:100%;" width="500" height="500" onclick="storeGuess(event)"></canvas>
</div>
```