# How to get mouse coordinates and to .push()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

so I have Graham scan algorithm which finding the convex hull of a finite set of points in the plane. I have some functions which are:

- taking coords (x, y) from textarea, drawing it on canvas, using
  Graham and in the end drawind lines;
- taking coords (x, y) from text file -//-;
- takind coords (x, y) from onclick event -//-;

Here you can check the project: https://codepen.io/Drew_D/pen/eWeJXj

So the problem is in the last one function in the end of .js code. I don't know how to add(draw new) points to existing canvas + it shold reload the algorithm...
So I need to take mouse coords, push them to the points[] and ch[] /* points[] this is an array with coordinates; ch[] this is an array of points' number like 1st point 2nd point etc. It's needed for the algorithm*/ and then refresh canvas with old + new points

> main.js

```
    function create_canvas() {
        var canvas_html = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas_html.id = "canvas";
        canvas_html.width = 600;
        canvas_html.height = 520;
        canvas_html.onclick="getCoords(event)"

        document.getElementById("canva_res").appendChild(canvas_html);

        return canvas_html.getContext('2d');
    }

    /**
     * рисует координатные оси
     */
function drawCoordLines() {
    canvas.beginPath();
    canvas.strokeStyle = '#fff';
    canvas.moveTo(300, 0);
    canvas.lineTo(300, 440);
    canvas.moveTo(0, 220);
    canvas.lineTo(600, 220);
    canvas.stroke();
    for (var x = 0.5; x < 610; x += 10) {
canvas.moveTo(x, 0);
canvas.lineTo(x, 450);
}
for (var y = 0.5; y < 450; y += 10) {
canvas.moveTo(0, y);
canvas.lineTo(600, y);
}canvas.strokeStyle = "#1abc9c";
canvas.stroke();
    canvas.closePath();
}

/**
 * рисует оболочку
 */
function drawHull() {

    canvas.beginPath();
    canvas.strokeStyle = '#fff';
    canvas.moveTo(300 + points[ h[0] ].x, 220 - points[ h[0] ].y);
    for(var i=1; i<h.length; i++){
        canvas.lineTo(300 + points[ h[i] ].x, 220 - points[ h[i] ].y);
    }

    canvas.closePath();
    canvas.stroke();
}

/**
 * рисует точки
 */
function drawPoints() {

    canvas.fillStyle = '#000';
    for(var i=0; i<points.length; i++){
        canvas.beginPath();
        canvas.arc(300 + points[i].x, 220 - points[i].y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2); // рисует точку
        canvas.closePath();
        canvas.fill();
    }


}

/**
 * обновляет и перерисовывает канвас
 */
function update() {
    canvas.clearRect(0, 0, 1500, 800); // очищаем канвас
    drawCoordLines();
    drawHull();
    drawPoints();
}

/**
 * считывает точки из формы
 */
function getPoints() {
    // получаем строку введенную в форму, и записываем в массив, разбив ее по запятой
    var coords = pointsV.value.split(", ");
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    points = [];
    ch = [];
    while (i < coords.length) {
        points[j++] = {
            'x': parseInt(coords[i++]),
            'y': parseInt(coords[i++])
        }
        ch.push(j-1);
    }
    graham();
}

/**
 * возращает векторное произведение
 */
function classify(vector, x1, y1) {
    return pr = (vector.x2 - vector.x1) * (y1 - vector.y1) - (vector.y2 - vector.y1) * (x1 - vector.x1);
}

/**
 * Выполняет поиск Грэхема и заполняет массив h, в котором будут перечислены точки, входящие в оболочку
 */
function graham() {
    var minI = 0; //номер нижней левой точки
    var min = points[0].x;
    // ищем нижнюю левую точку
    for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
        if (points[i].x < min) {
            min = points[i].x;
            minI = i;
        }
    }
    // делаем нижнюю левую точку активной
    ch[0] = minI;
    ch[minI] = 0;

    // сортируем вершины в порядке "левизны"
    for (var i = 1; i < ch.length - 1; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < ch.length; j++) {
            var cl = classify({
                'x1': points[ ch[0] ].x,
                'y1': points[ ch[0] ].y,
                'x2': points[ ch[i] ].x,
                'y2': points[ ch[i] ].y
            }, points[ ch[j] ].x, points[ ch[j] ].y) // функция classify считает векторное произведение.

            // если векторное произведение меньше 0, следовательно вершина j левее вершины i.Меняем их местами
            if (cl < 0) {
                temp = ch[i];
                ch[i] = ch[j];
                ch[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    //записываем в стек вершины, которые точно входят в оболочку
    h = [];
    h[0] = ch[0];
    h[1] = ch[1];


    for (var i = 2; i < ch.length; i++) {
        while (classify({
            'x1': points[ h[h.length - 2] ].x,
            'y1': points[ h[h.length - 2] ].y,
            'x2': points[ h[h.length - 1] ].x,
            'y2': points[ h[h.length - 1] ].y
        }, points[ ch[i] ].x, points[ ch[i] ].y) < 0) {
            h.pop(); // пока встречается правый поворот, убираем точку из оболочки
        }
        h.push(ch[i]); // добавляем новую точку в оболочку
    }

    // обновляем канвас
    update();
}

/**
 * выполняется когда страница будет полностью загружена в браузер
 */
window.onload = function() {
    canvas = create_canvas();

    // массив точек, из которых строим выпуклую оболочку
    points = [{
            'x': 10,
            'y': 20
        }, {
            'x': 60,
            'y': 160
        }, {
            'x': 110,
            'y': 20
        }, {
            'x': -60,
            'y': 80
        },
        {
            'x': 70,
            'y': 140
        }];

    // массив номеров точек, потребуется для алгоритма Грэхема
    ch = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

    // искомая оболочка, будет заполнена функцией graham
    h = []

    // получаем форму ввода
    pointsV = document.getElementById('pointos');
    graham();

    document.getElementById('canvas').onclick = function(e) {
      var i = 1;
      var j = 1;

      points = [];
      ch = [];
      points.push({'x': e.clientX, 'y': e.clientY});
      ch.push(j);
      j++;
      graham();
    }
}
```

Comment: simply remove this : 
*points = [];
   ch = [];*

Comment: @Jonasw no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like we need to reset the ch array at each graham call:

```
function graham(){
     ch=ch.map((e,i)=>i);// creates [0,1,2,3,...]
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you dont want to reset the client array on click, and you want the relative position:

```
document.getElementById('canvas').onclick = function(e) {
  var x;
  var y;
   if (e.pageX || e.pageY) { 
      x = e.pageX;
      y = e.pageY;
   }else { 
      x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft; 
      y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
   } 
   x -= this.offsetLeft;
   y -= this.offsetTop;
  points.push({x:x-300,y:-y});// i think you need relative positions here...
  ch.push(ch.length);//thats all... no need for a counter...

  graham();
}
```

Ressource: [How do I get the coordinates of a mouse click on a canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-a-canvas-element)

Comment: @charlietfl isnt it an *enhanced object literal* introduced in ES6?

Comment: but not supported in all browsers

Comment: @charlietfl yep, so a fair comment would be *please note that this is ES6* , *not pushing a valid object* sounds like *your code is wrong!* ...

Comment: @Jonasw i updated https://codepen.io/Drew_D/pen/eWeJXj to your last version I think there are also problem with coords

Comment: @Jonasw I gues i need something like transforming screen coordinates to canvas

Comment: @AndrewDushkin *canvas.arc(300 + points[i].x, 220 - points[i].y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2)* thats the problem i think...

Comment: @AndrewDushkin as far as i can see it is *nearly* working! So may try it outside of a fiddle, they can mess up things sometimes...

Comment: @Jonasw hey I found something, can you help me to figure out how to do the similar thing in my code? http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/index.html#17QBL9#1

Comment: @Jonasw the problem is that taking the global coords but not canvas coords so it tries to draw the real one but they are too big. So we need something like this "Translate mouse click coordinates to canvas coordinates"

Comment: @AndrewDushkin i found a way to make it nearly work... i will edit

Comment: @Jonasw This will be better   points.push({x:x-300,y:-y+220}); check here http://cw.lukas.te.ua/  buuut anyway the point of that alghorithm that it shold to draw a convex hull, so all point should be inside of that stuff

Comment: Ok, thanks) the algurithm is working, because two first functions (points from textarea and from txt are working well) so there is something when we call that     graham(); in the end