# How to find coordinates in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, coordinate

I have a Raphael paper and I want find the coordinates relative to my paper

My `html`:

```
<div style='width:100%;'>
  <div id='mycanvas' class='canvas'></div>
</div>
```

My `Javascript`:

```
var mypaper = Raphael(mycanvas, '100%', '100%');
...
document.getElementById('mycanvas').onmouseover=function(event) {
    var canvasPos = {
        x: this.offsetLeft,
        y: this.offsetTop
    };
    var coord = {
        x: event.pageX-canvasPos.x,
        y: event.pageY-canvasPos.y
    };
};
```

I expect `coord.x` and `coord.y` to be zero for the top left corner of mypaper but it isn't

Comment: So, what are they?

Comment: Well... I don't know what they rappresent. Maybe absolute position on the screen?

Comment: what are the values for canvasPos, like the number?

Comment: Yes, they are numbers but different from pageX, screenX, clientX

Comment: I mean what is their literall value. i.e. `console.log(convasPos.x)` spits out what?

Comment: console.log(convasPos.x, convasPos.y) = 40 1342

Comment: Do you have styling applied to the canvas class?

Comment: For the class I have a border from javascript and I have some style for the divs but by id

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146701/discussion-between-fabio-and-mburnham).

Answer (score 2):

So at last, I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18053642/5704198)

```
function getCursorPosition(canvas, event) {
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
var y = event.clientY - rect.top;
console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y);
```

}