# What's wrong with the addEventListeners

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, addeventlistener

the vector should be able to be pulled and repositioned. ugh!. I have it up on fiddle at

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mancod/tuzv1cg9/2/)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('cv2'),
  c = canvas.getContext('2d');

var wide = canvas.width;
var high = canvas.height;

var p0 = {
  x: 50,
  y: 250
};

var p1 = {
  x: 250,
  y: 270
};

var p2 = {
  x: 250,
  y: 150
};


draw();

function draw() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawPoint(p0);
  drawPoint(p1);
  drawPoint(p2);
  drawLines();

}


function drawPoint(p) {
  c.beginPath();
  c.lineWidth = 2;
  c.arc(p.x, p.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  c.stroke();
  c.fill();

}

function drawLines() {
  c.beginPath();
  c.lineWidth = 2;
  c.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
  c.lineTo(p0.x, p0.y);
  c.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
  c.stroke();
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
var dragPoint;

function findDragPoint(x, y) {
  if (hitTest(p0, x, y)) return p0;
  if (hitTest(p1, x, y)) return p1;
  if (hitTest(p2, x, y)) return p2;
  return null;
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
  dragPoint = findDragPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
  if (dragPoint) {
    dragPoint.x = event.clientX;
    dragPoint.y = event.clientY;
    draw();
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
  }
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
  dragPoint.x = event.clientX;
  dragPoint.y = event.cleintY;
  draw();
}

function onMouseUp() {
  canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  canvas.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
}



function hitTest(p, x, y) {
  var dx = p.x - x,
    dy = p.y - y;
  return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= 10;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='cv2' width=800 height=500></canvas>
```

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the coordinates of a mouse click on a canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-a-canvas-element)

Comment: There's a spelling mistake in "onMouseMove": `cleintY`. If you fix that it works (when clicking the top area of the circles) unless the canvas is scrolled. To fix the scrolling issue, see the duplicate issue

Comment: Thanks you @NineBerry. It's one step forward with two back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing messy with JavaScript, you just need a lot more practice...

Few things on your code, as they point out in the comments you have a typo `cleintY`, also you have to substract the canvas.offset to get the correct position of the mouse.

Those points should be an array that way you can add more and everything will work.

Here is your code working

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('cv2');
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

var points = [{x:18, y:12},{x:50, y:50},{x:180, y:90},{x:250, y:50}];
var dragPoint = null;
draw();

function draw() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  points.forEach(p => drawPoint(p));
  drawLines();
}

function drawPoint(p) {
  c.beginPath();
  c.lineWidth = 2;
  c.arc(p.x, p.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  c.stroke();
  c.fill();
}

function drawLines() {
  c.beginPath();
  c.lineWidth = 2;
  points.forEach(p => c.lineTo(p.x, p.y));
  c.stroke();
}

function findDragPoint(x, y) {
  for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    if (hitTest(points[i], x, y)) return points[i];
  };  
  return null;
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
  dragPoint = findDragPoint(event.clientX- canvas.offsetLeft, event.clientY- canvas.offsetTop);
  if (dragPoint) {
    dragPoint.x = event.clientX- canvas.offsetLeft;
    dragPoint.y = event.clientY- canvas.offsetTop;
    draw();
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
  }
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
  dragPoint.x = event.clientX- canvas.offsetLeft;
  dragPoint.y = event.clientY- canvas.offsetTop;
  draw();
}

function onMouseUp() {
  canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  canvas.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
}

function hitTest(p, x, y) {
  var dx = p.x - x, dy = p.y - y;
  return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= 10;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='cv2' width=400 height=120></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you. I agree on the practice. Most appreciated. Just when I believe I grasp, wham.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is to replace `clientX` / `clientY` of the event with `offetX` and `offsetY` respectively. These properties give you the actual mouse cursor position on the canvas independently of scrolling position of the canvas and canvas margins.

See also [How do I get the coordinates of a mouse click on a canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-a-canvas-element)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('cv2'),
      c = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  var wide = canvas.width;
  var high = canvas.height;

var p0 = {
  x: 50,
  y: 250
};

var p1 = {
  x: 250,
  y: 270
};
  
  var p2 = {
  x: 250,
  y: 150
};
  
  
  draw();
  
  function draw() {
    c.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  drawPoint(p0);
  drawPoint(p1);
  drawPoint(p2);
  drawLines();
    
  }
  
  
  function drawPoint(p) {
    c.beginPath();
    c.lineWidth=2;
    c.arc (p.x, p.y, 10, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    c.stroke();
    c.fill();
    
  }
  
  function drawLines() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.lineWidth=2;
    c.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
    c.lineTo(p0.x, p0.y);
    c.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
    c.stroke();
  }
  
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
var dragPoint;

function findDragPoint(x,y) {
  if(hitTest(p0, x, y)) return p0;
  if(hitTest(p1, x, y)) return p1;
  if(hitTest(p2, x, y)) return p2;
  return null;
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
  dragPoint = findDragPoint(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
  if(dragPoint) {
    dragPoint.x = event.offsetX;
    dragPoint.y = event.offsetY;
    draw();
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
  }
}
function onMouseMove(event) {
   dragPoint.x = event.offsetX;
   dragPoint.y = event.offsetY;
   draw();
}

function onMouseUp() {
  canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  canvas.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
}



function hitTest(p, x, y) {
  var dx = p.x - x,
      dy = p.y - y;
      return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) <=10;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='cv2' width=800 height=500></canvas>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z6t2jw5d/