# modifying the polygraph on a canvas is not working when canvas image is scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, rotation

The current issue I am having is that when I scroll the image on the canvas the ability to manipulate the drawn polygraph is lost.   Is there some way to address this in the code?

In the following  jsfiddle.net/heldersepu/egt92403/36    and it is  related to a post I put up in [Validate if mouse position is within rotated rectangle in HTML5 Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69110104/validate-if-mouse-position-is-within-rotated-rectangle-in-html5-canvas)   and got help from Helder Sepulveda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using event.clientY and event.clientX to get the position of the mouse, those 2 properties is relative to the screen.

You can either use event.pageY and event.pageX to get the coordinates relative to the document (those 2 properties are not effected by scroll)
Or offset the positions your self with window.scrollY and window.scrollX, an example of that can be seen here https://jsfiddle.net/faex5Lqc/2/ (important part `event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop + window.scrollY`)

Comment: Quick question for Benjaco.   I am back on this project.  How did you generate the image for the farm at https://i.postimg.cc/SNjPPZGJ/farms-map.png?   Thanks.  Jack

Comment: @JackStein, I didn't generate anything, do you mean how would I do it? If so, have the different elements and geomatries in different layers, and then draw the grass, then all roads, then trees ect.